# Regex gives error

Tags: java, regex

Continuing with the post at
[Regular expression to allow a set of characters and disallow others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705672/regular-expression-to-allow-a-set-of-characters-and-disallow-others/705990#705990)

Does anybody know why the below would occur?

I get the below error when I create a regular expression as:

```
[^@*–’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRNEŽDTCnežuUIti—¿„”]+
```

and enter any of these restricted characters in the input field

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler$RERange.delete(RECompiler.java:1326)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler$RERange.remove(RECompiler.java:1417)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler$RERange.include(RECompiler.java:1459)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler$RERange.include(RECompiler.java:1470)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.characterClass(RECompiler.java:699)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.terminal(RECompiler.java:863)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.closure(RECompiler.java:942)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.branch(RECompiler.java:1151)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.expr(RECompiler.java:1203)
    at org.apache.regexp.RECompiler.compile(RECompiler.java:1281)
    at org.apache.regexp.RE.(RE.java:495)
    at org.apache.regexp.RE.(RE.java:480)
```

but this expression works perfectly fine

```
[^@*–’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRN]+
```

Also,

```
[^@*–’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠR„”]+
```

works but

```
[^@*–’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRNE]+
```

does not work and gives the above error.

Is there a limit to the number of characters that can be disallowed like the way above?

Regards,
Udit Sud

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem to me, but Java's not my thing

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, it works with the .NET Regex engine. I suspect it is a bug in that particular Java Regex implementation.

Comment: @Udit - what happens when you leave out the "E"?

Answer (score 3):

The dash (minus sign) has special meaning in character classes. It defines ranges of consecutive characters, like `"a-z"`.

There may exist a consecutive range for `"*–’"`, but I guess this is not your intention. You probably wanted the literal dash, and I suspect the exception you are seeing has something to do with this.

Instead of this:

```
[^@*–’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRNEŽDTCnežuUIti—¿„”]+
----^ (this is the error)
```

Try:

```
[^@*’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRNEŽDTCnežuUIti—¿„”–]+
-----------------------------------------^ (this okay)
```

or

```
[-^@*’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRNEŽDTCnežuUIti—¿„”]+
-^ (this okay as well)
```

or

```
[^@*\–’”“\r\nœçsÇSgGšcrŠRNEŽDTCnežuUIti—¿„”]+
----^^ (this okay as well)
```

Comment: +1. Now I do wonder, if it doesn't give any error with the .Net engine, does it behave as expected?!

Comment: I guess that "*–’" in fact *is* a valid range, but something about it makes the RECompiler barf. Maybe I'm wrong, but the dash is quite suspicious.

Comment: My guess is that it trips up on including more of the same character in one character class.  Could /[aa]/ crash it?

Comment: Unless someone actually looks at RECompiler.java, we can only guess. :-) In theory, [aa] is fine and should not cause an error in any implementation.

Comment: That's not a hyphen you're pointing at, it's an en-dash (U+2013), and the other one is an em-dash (U+2014). Neither has any special meaning. The error is due to the bug Eddie pointed out, and not anything the OP is doing.

Comment: @Alan: It looked like a hyphen to me, though I admit I didn't cross-check. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

See http://webui.sourcelabs.com/jakarta-regexp/issues/22804 -- an old version of this package *did* limit the maximum number of allowed ranges, to 16. This was fixed in 2003, but it's conceivable that they just raised the limit a little bit.  (?)

Anyway, I always use the Java built-in Regex parser for any new work, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some error in apache regexp parser. Can you use a standart one (java.util.regex)?

Comment: Only author of question can mark this post as "right asnwer"? Too bad he didn't do this.. :(